# Croppie plugin crops the image incorrectly when i use modal window

Tags: javascript, croppie

[https://codepen.io/kurtzalexo/pen/jOYwQNq](Codepen.io)
I use cropie and tingle.js. Without a modal window everything works fine.
[This is what happens, when i crop image from the edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMKp1.png)

Tried:
https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/issues/258, https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/issues/764, https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/issues/247

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed these styles from tingle and everything start working correctly.

```
.tingle-modal--visible .tingle-modal-box {
  animation: scale .2s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55) forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

To:

```
.tingle-modal--visible .tingle-modal-box {
    animation: scal .2s cubic-bezier(.68, -.55, .265, 1.55) none;
}

@keyframes scal {
  0% {
      top: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
      top: 0;
  }
}
```

It looks like croppy reads the size of the container before applying the transform animation.